# What is the difference between an OverlayFS and a bind mount?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Here is my understanding:

- Bind mount only keeps files from upper file system accessible. No files from lower fs under target path would be accessible.
- OverlayFS also keeps the files of lower file system  that does not exist in upper file system  accessible under target path.

Is this correct? Any other major differences?

Comment: I think you laid out a pertinent question and it has some merit.  Too bad you got absolutely noone to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is roughly correctly.

The underlay is typically read-only. The overlay is read-write.

If a file exists in the underlay it can be read by the overlay. If the overlay wants to write to a file that exists in the underlay, then the OS will create a copy of the file that exists in the underlay and write the new version in the overlay. The OS is responsible for the accounting/bookkeeping of keeping track of what layer owns what files.

The same sort of procedure is followed for deletes.

[image: Overlay]